# Paste worksheet range into email body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email, worksheet

I have a sheet to fill information regarding critical issues to manage into war rooms.

The team sends announcements when a critical issue is happening.

As the old process lacked standardization in these announcements, I created a sheet with a custom layout for e-mails.

To prevent workers editing this layout, I protected the worksheets and created buttons with macros to generate these announcements.

Below is a screenshot from this worksheet. The cells start at B6 and end at L27. The worksheet name is "Planilha5".

When I click the SEND button on the worksheet, I need a new message in Microsoft Outlook 365 to be invoked and filled with the information and the worksheet defined range pasted into the body of the mail message.

[image: Announcement screenshot]

```vb
Sub EnviarAbertura()
    Dim Outlook As Object, Novo_Email As Object, Email_Body As String, b1 As Variant

    b1 = Planilha5.Range("B6:L27")

    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

    Email_Body = b1
    
    Set Novo_Email = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    Corpo = Planilha5.Range("B6:L27").Copy
    
    With Novo_Email
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "centraldecomandotd@natura.net"
        .Subject = Planilha5.Range("G4")
        .Body = Email_Body
        .Display
    End With
    
End Sub
```

When I comment these lines the script works without the body filled.

```vb
b1 = Planilha5.Range("B6:L27")

Email_Body = b1

.Body = Email_Body`
```

[image: VBA Script working properly]

I have pasted manually the worksheet range into a screenshot below to show what I expect.

[image: Expected results]

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Welcome Gulkas! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways of setting the message body based on the Excel data:

1. Build the HTML markup based on the worksheet content. That is basically what Ron described on the [Mail Range/Selection in the body of the mail](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) page where you can find the following sample code:

   ```
   Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
    End Function
   ```

   Note, after getting the HTML markup you need to use the `HTMLBody` property, not the plain text `Body`.
2. You can copy the required range in Excel by using the [Range.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) method and then paste directly to the message body by using the Word editor, see the `WordEditor` property of the `Inspector` class. The property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Eugene,

I've tried to use the Ron's code adapting to my need, but the result was not the one expected.

When I run the macro, it shown perfectly on Microsoft Outlook:
https://imgur.com/a/JFMDD5B

But when the people receive this message, there is no image into the body:
On Microsoft Outlook: https://imgur.com/a/0guaCbF
On Outlook Web: https://imgur.com/a/Ob5NN66

Do you have any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question with the exact code you have used for that.

Comment: I already posted a new answer for this thread.

Comment: A separate question shouldn't not be posted as another answer.